# IBAction opening URL for Table Bar cell interaction in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, ibaction

Wasn't able to find the answer I was looking for for this... (Swift 2.0)

I have a table view Controller that houses several table bar cells. Each cell has a desired action that is supposed to happen once the cell is selected by a user.

The way I have it setup is that it opens a completely new view and then that view is programmed to instantly open said url.

See here [Storyboard.main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLnfE.png) 
OR here is an example of the .swift file for the secondary view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class twitterSocial: UIViewController, UIApplicationDelegate {

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let twitterID: NSURL = NSURL(string: "...")!
    let twitterWebURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "...")!

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(twitterID){
        //checks to see if Twitter is installed
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twitterID)
    }
    else{
        // Twitter NOT installed - Safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twitterWebURL)
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    print("View Will Dissapear")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

is it possible to program this in such a way that the table bar cell will open a desired url without having to include a second view? Because when a user then returns to the application, the current view is blank and they then have to return to the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a tebleViewDelegate method that gets called when a user taps on the cell.

```
let twitterIDs: [NSURL] = [NSURL(string: "...")!]
let twitterWebURLs: [NSURL] = [NSURL(string: "...")!]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(twitterIDs[indexPath.row]){
        //checks to see if Twitter is installed
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twitterIDs[indexPath.row])
    }
    else{
        // Twitter NOT installed - Safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twitterWebURLs[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this but it should perform the same as if you opened it up on a separate View Controller.

Comment: Thank you. But how could this be done to include separate actions of the same kind for each table cell?  I was thinking a switch statement for the Index Path? then each case represents each recurring cell in the table, with individual code to execute at each selection.

The code you gave me compiles but it doesn't quite work, I added a tableViewController.swift "nib" file to add the code to it. Maybe it needs to be in a regular view controller? the table view is in a pre-made table view controller. Maybe making it a regular view and adding the table view on top of it would work better?